# Sudo apt-get error: flAbsPath on /var/lib/dpkg/status failed - No such file or directory

Tags: linux, apt-get

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
Reading package lists... Error!
E: flAbsPath on /var/lib/dpkg/status failed - realpath (2: No such file or directory)
E: Could not open file  - open (2: No such file or directory)
E: Problem opening 
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Whenever I try to install any software I get this error. How do I solve this ?

Comment: Apparently related:  [How to recreate /var/lib/dpkg/status?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/161866/80216) (on U&L), and [How do I rebuild a corrupt dpkg status file?](https://askubuntu.com/q/4834/325633), [Corrupt dpkg status file](https://askubuntu.com/q/527064/325633), and [How to recreate /var/lib/dpkg/status?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1102547/325633) (on AU).

Answer (score 15):

I faced a similar issue recently with ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, what worked for me is as following -

**First you need to create an empty file, as following :-**

```
adminuser@sandbox:~$ sudo touch /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Now run update & upgrade :-

```
adminuser@sandbox:~$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Probable you may end up seeing something like this --

```
adminuser@sandbox:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.

adminuser@sandbox:~$ apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

But if you logout and login back, your MOTD will show you that some updates are pending -

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-96-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

108 packages can be updated.
27 updates are security updates.
```

At this point, you need to run dist-upgrade -

```
adminuser@sandbox:~$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

This should fix the issue, but make sure it shouldn't push you ahead to actually upgrade the Ubuntu to a new version. As well as I understand, until the launch of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS this should work.
Good Luck

Comment: This worked for me. thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Step 1:
cd /

Step 2:
cd var/lib/

Step 3:
mkdir dpkg

Step 4:
touch status

This worked for me. :)

Comment: This solution works for me. I accidentally remove `dpkg` directory.

Comment: I had a broken build and had to run fsck to fix it. In the process that must have removed the dpkg folder - this was my chosen solve.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/dpkg/{alternatives,info,parts,triggers,updates}
```

**Still you need to copy this file**

```
sudo cp /var/backups/dpkg.status.0 /var/lib/dpkg/status

apt-get download dpkg
sudo dpkg -i dpkg*.deb
apt-get download base-files
sudo dpkg -i base-files*.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get check
```

Answer (score 1):

My `/var/lib/dpkg/status` file got deleted and according to apt I had no packages installed, as it determines them from the `status` file. I used the following method to regenerate the `/var/lib/dpkg/status` file. The method worked very fine for me in Kali GNU/Linux, which is Debian-based.

### NOTE:

- This method assumes that all installed packages have created entries in the `/usr/share/doc` directory.
- This method starts from an empty `/var/lib/dpkg/status` file.
- This method may not work if you have more than 1 repository providing the same package. If you do have more than 1 repository providing the same package, temporarily disable the subsidiary repo, then delete the package cache lists for the repo in `/var/lib/apt/lists/`.

1. Delete the current `status` and `status-old` files. Make a backup of the files before deletion incase you get errors.

   ```
   mkdir ~/dpkg-status-backup
   cp /var/lib/dpkg/{status,status-old} ~/dpkg-status-backup
   rm /var/lib/dpkg/{status,status-old}
   ```
2. Get list of all packages installed, one package per line. 
   Note: it's `1` (one) not `l` (lower-case `L`).

   ```
   ls -1 /usr/share/doc > installed-packages.list
   ```
3. Rewrite the packages list into one line.

   ```
   tr '\n' ' ' < installed-packages.list > installed-packages-one-line.list
   ```
4. Create an empty `status` file to enable apt-cache to run.

   ```
   touch /var/lib/dpkg/status
   ```
5. Generate package records using apt-cache.

   ```
   cat installed-packages-one-line.list | xargs apt-cache show > raw-status-file
   ```
6. The `raw-status-file` may contain `Status:` fields for some packages. Delete them to avoid duplication.

   ```
   sed -i '/^Status:/d' raw-status-file
   ```
7. Add the `Status:`  field for every package to indicate to apt & dpkg that they're installed.

   ```
   sed -i 's/^Package:.*/&\nStatus: install ok installed/' raw-status-file
   ```
8. Remove fields unwanted by dpkg in `status` file: `SHA1:`, `SHA256:`, `MD5sum:`, `Description-md5:`, `Size:` & `Filename:` .

   ```
   sed -i '/^MD5sum:/d' raw-status-file
   sed -i '/^SHA1:/d' raw-status-file
   sed -i '/^SHA256:/d' raw-status-file
   sed -i '/^Size:/d' raw-status-file
   sed -i '/^Filename:/d' raw-status-file
   sed -i '/^Description-md5:/d' raw-status-file
   ```
9. The resultant `raw-status-file` after running the above commands is now the actual dpkg `status` file.

   ```
   mv raw-status-file status
   ```
10. Copy the `status` file to `/var/lib/dpkg/` as `status` and `status-old`.

    ```
    cp status /var/lib/dpkg/status
    cp status /var/lib/dpkg/status-old
    ```
11. Now run dpkg to validate your new status file. If you get errors, take hints from dpkg's error report, & solve accordingly. If you get no errors, then the `status` file has the correct syntax.

    ```
    dpkg --get-selections
    ```
12. Re-enable the disabled repos then run apt to update package cache lists to prevent the error `packages have unmet dependencies`.

    ```
    apt update
    ```
13. If you run into `packages have unmet dependencies` error in apt, then make sure you've enabled the subsidiary repos that provide the dependencies, then run aptitude. I prefer `aptitude` because it's better at solving package installation errors.

    ```
    aptitude full-upgrade
    ```

If you get no errors/your errors have been resolved from apt or dpkg, and get "*PACKAGE* is already the newest version..." when you try to install a program you're sure is already installed, such as `coreutils`, then you've successfully regenerated the dpkg `status` file.

Clean-up the temp files created and the backup.

```
rm installed-packages.list installed-packages-one-line.list status
rm -r ~/dpkg-status-backup
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to recreate a /var/lib/dpkg file structure, which does require backups or luck (and maybe both). See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/161866/how-to-recreate-var-lib-dpkg-status).